# Shallow and deep copies for lists and dictionaries

Tags: python, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I am trying to better understand shallow and deep copies in Python, especially when dictionaries and lists are involved.

Let's say I have a list of dictionaries and I want to copy values of specific keys (`'a'`) into a different list of dictionaries under a different key name (`'x'`):

```
list_dict = [{'a': 1}, {'a': 2}]

dict1 = {}
dict1['x'] = {}
list1 = []

for entry in list_dict:
    dict1['x'] = entry['a']
    list1.append(dict1)

>>>print list1
[{'x': 2}, {'x': 2}]
```

Obviously, not what I wanted. However, I know that I can specify `.copy()` for a dictionary to create a shallow copy:

```
for entry in list_dict:
    dict1['x'] = entry['a']
    list1.append(dict1.copy())

>>>print list1
[{'x': 1}, {'x': 2}]
```

Even though it's shallow, it works. Now, let's make it a bit different - I want to copy it not to `dict1['x']`, but to `dict1['x']['y']`:

```
for entry in list_dict:
    dict1['x']['y'] = entry['a']
    list1.append(dict1.copy())

>>>print list1
[{'x': {'y': 2}}, {'x': {'y': 2}}]
```

Back to square one - it doesn't work! So, this is the **first question** - why did it stop working?

And the **second question** is, why does adding the last line make it work?

```
for entry in list_dict:
    dict1['x']['y'] = entry['a']
    list1.append(dict1.copy())
    dict1['x'] = {}

>>>print list1
[{'x': {'y': 1}}, {'x': {'y': 2}}]
```

Thank you very much in advance!

P.S. I know that I can do `import copy` and then `copy.deepcopy()`, however I'm interested in learning why does the shallow copy stop working when I add one more level of dictionary and why does the workaround of "resetting" the dictionary work.

Comment: why do you think one is called shallow and the other deep?

Comment: the answer is in the docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for entry in list_dict:
    dict1['x']['y'] = entry['a']
    list1.append(dict1.copy())

>>>print list1
[{'x': {'y': 2}}, {'x': {'y': 2}}]
```

*Back to square one - it doesn't work! So, this is the first question - why did it stop working?*

Because, you now have **three** dictionaries:

1. `{'x': {'y': 2}}`
2. `{'x': {'y': 2}}`
3. `{'y': 2}`

   Only two of which are are "copied" (1 and 2). They are both referencing 3. Changes in 3 reflect in 1 and 2.

---

*And the second question is, why does adding the last line make it work?*

```
for entry in list_dict:
    dict1['x']['y'] = entry['a']
    list1.append(dict1.copy())
    dict1['x'] = {}

>>>print list1
[{'x': {'y': 1}}, {'x': {'y': 2}}]
```

Because, you're now creating a **new dictionary** on each iteration (using `{}`), and then you change it. You've created the first one in your initializing code. You're not changing the references of old dictionaries in the list. Only the one about to be inserted.

**Future tip:** Best thing to do in this case, to help you follow the code, is either use debug mode and step through the program. Or do what lazy people do and simply print within the objects during the iterations to see what their values are.

Comment: I think I got the first part, thank you! However, still struggling with the second one. Why does creating this new empty dictionary not empty the shallow copy? In other words, why does `dict1['x']['y'] = entry['a']` change the contents of `list1`, but `dict1['x'] = {}` doesn't? Is it just because the first one has 2 levels of nested, and the second one doesn't? But then if I do `dict1['x'] = {'a': 123}` - the result is the 'y' values do get saved as well...

Comment: `dict1['x']` -> give me whatever is in `dict1` under key `'x'`. `dict1['x']['y]` -> give me whatever is under `dict1`  in key `'x'`, and then give me whatever is under key `'y'` in that result. So, what you're doing in the first case alters `dict1` directly. What you're doing in the second case alters an object `dict1` references to. You may also notice that while `'x'` is a key in `dict1`, `'y'` is a key **in an object in `dict1`**. You can try it yourself by printing all keys in `dict1` using `print dict1.keys()` and you'll see `y` isn't there.